# The Ajax Success Function show double notification of jquery how to disable the second one?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is the code which I have used for deleting the records but when the deletion is successfully done. this `Waqas.notification("Data Deleted Successfully","success");`  notification is shown Twice at the top of the page.

```
function DeleteUser(deleteid) {
        $('#YesDelete').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "../Ajax/CrudSlider.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    deleteid: deleteid
                },
                success: function(data) {
                     readRecords();
                     var split = data.split("::");
                     Waqas.notification("Data Deleted Successfully","success");

                }
            });

        });
```

And this is code which deletes records from the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteid']))
{
    $user_id = $_POST['deleteid']; 
    $selectquery1="select * from slider where slider_id = $user_id"; 
    $cm= mysqli_query($conn,$selectquery1);
    $result =mysqli_fetch_array($cm);
    $path = $result['slider_image']; 
    $deletequery = " DELETE FROM `slider` WHERE slider_id ='$user_id' ";
    unlink($path);
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($conn,$deletequery)) {    
        exit(mysqli_error());
    }
}
```

This is the Delete model. it appears when clicked on `DeleteUser()`.

```
<div class="modal Delete-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Warning</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" id="DeleteHiddenID">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Identification">Are You sure to delete the record.</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" id="YesDelete">Yes</button>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-right: 10px;">No</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
```

Comment: may be `readRecords();` is calling it

Comment: When and where is `DeleteUser` called?

Comment: no readRecords(); is just showing the data in tables.

Comment: An indented code is more pleasant to read (readable in fact)

Comment: <td><span style="cursor:pointer; color:#464C6B;" onclick="DeleteUser(<?=$row['slider_id']?>)" class="fa fa-trash" ></span>
</td>

Comment: `DeleteUser` doesn't delete. It binds a function to the click event of the `YesDelete` element. Can you add your complete HTML relevant to this?

Comment: i have updated the question.

Comment: Where in your Javascript do you show the modal dialog?

Comment: this model dialog is shown outside the javascript code. it is in html tag

Comment: I cant underastand why you put " $('#YesDelete').click(function() {"      in the    
 "function DeleteUser(deleteid) {". separate them.   And where you call DeleteUser In HTML Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding a click event to the `YesDelete` button each time you click on the delete button. You should instead only assign the event once so you should move it outside the `DeleteUser` function. Afterwards all you need to do is update the `deleteid` sent to the server.

The easiest way to do that would be to assign the id to a global variable when `DeleteUser` is called. The click event will then use that id when calling the server.

e.g.

```
var deleteid;

$(function() {

  $('#YesDelete').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "../Ajax/CrudSlider.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        deleteid: deleteid
      },
      success: function(data) {
        readRecords();
        var split = data.split("::");
        Waqas.notification("Data Deleted Successfully", "success");
      }
    });

  });

});

function DeleteUser(id) {
  deleteid = id;
}
```